# Partial or Lightweight Replica of MySQL on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, replication, database-partitioning

I have a MySQL database on Amazon RDS, few of the tables are growing fast so we are thinking to have a lighter/smaller database (or may be just specific tables) replica so that we can fetch current dashboards or reports from there.

And use the original larger database for on-demand heavy reporting.

I have tried AWS read-replica but that seems to copy entire data. But I only want data of say last 3 months only.

Please suggest how can we have an updated lighter replica.

P.S. I would also like to know if there is some other way to do that e-g table partition or something. I would appreciate some details.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by using a read-replica of RDS MySQL database with the read-only flag set as zero (or false).

This way, I was able to flush older data from the replica database periodically through a scheduled stored procedure.

To modify the read-only flag of an RDS replica, we need to create a Parameter Group in RDS console and attach that to the replica instance. Parameter Group has many flags and options but I only needed to set `read-only = 0` and leave everything else as is.